# How can I delete a comment on a "locked" question?

Tags: support, comments

I wrote some comments on a question that subsequently got locked:

[Choosing between two job offers: big brand vs smaller more fulfilling role](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/164553/choosing-between-two-job-offers-big-brand-vs-smaller-more-fulfilling-role/164558#comment533202_164558)

In an effort to not contribute to "our comment problem", I like to go back and clean up any comments after they have been read. But since the question is now locked, it appears that I cannot.

Am I missing something? Is there a way I can delete them?

Comment: I can delete them for you if you wish...

Comment: (done).... now regarding to your question, I think that as long as it's locked there is no way for you to do that. It seems that only mods can modify things after a post is locked (not an official answer).

Comment: @DarkCygnus - thanks. Maybe you can clean this one up as well? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/164553/choosing-between-two-job-offers-big-brand-vs-smaller-more-fulfilling-role#comment533164_164553

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**

While I can't find a primary source on this, [this feature request on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330667/let-us-delete-our-own-comments-even-if-the-post-is-locked) confirms the behaviour you're seeing: you're unable to interact with any comments on a locked thread and that includes being unable to delete your own comments.

In future, **simply flag your comments** with reason "obsolete" **or the post** for moderator attention with reason "other" and we can clean up the comments for you.

Note: in this case a "historical lock" was applied. As per [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247501/allow-flags-on-locked-posts?noredirect=1&lq=1) this will also **prevent you from flagging anything** on that page. We'll try to avoid this specific type of lock in future.